# How to write generic methods in coded ui which can used with any type of control irrespective of its property same or changed?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, automation, ui-automation, coded-ui-tests

I am using coded ui automation in Visual Studio 2012. So I have a  requirement where I have to write some generic/common methods which can be used with any type of UI control.

I an new to coded ui. How to write such methods so that i can reuse it in code.

Basically, for example I want common methods for verifying certain control/Tiles/TAB/Objects is visible or not on UI.

Comment: are you talking about generic method to identify controls or genreic method to act on previously identified controls?

Comment: Can you be more specific about your requirements? CodedUi tests are just basic .NET classes, so you can use the standard ways, create a helper class, use extension methods, create a base class for your TestClass. If objects are of different types, you may have to implement the same method multiple times, with the exact type as a differentiator. If you have little experience with .NET (C# or VB.NET), I encourage you to study basic object orientation in .NET.

Answer (score 1):

NOTE:- I found below solution from some blog, might be this could be helpful.

To replace the UIMap, we are going to use the power of Generics in the .Net Framework. For ease of use in our testing, I built a static extension so that I could attach it to any UITestControl and use a SearchFor method to find things. As you can see in my code below, it is pretty straight forward. I use dynamics to pass in variables that I can use for both the SearchProperties and FilterProperties to go find items in the application. If you need to find more information on the controls you can use the “Coded UI Test Builder” to get more detailed information.

---

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Blog.Example
{
    public static class CodedUIExtension
    {

        public static T SearchFor<T>(this UITestControl _this, dynamic searchProperties, dynamic filterProperties = null) where T : UITestControl, new()
        {
            T ctrl = new T();
            ctrl.Container = _this;
            IEnumerable<string> propNames = ((object)searchProperties).GetPropertiesForObject();

            foreach (var item in propNames)
            {
                ctrl.SearchProperties.Add(item, ((object)searchProperties).GetPropertyValue(item).ToString());
            }

            if (filterProperties != null)
            {
                propNames = ((object)filterProperties).GetPropertiesForObject();
                foreach (var item in propNames)
                {
                    ctrl.FilterProperties.Add(item, ((object)filterProperties).GetPropertyValue(item).ToString());
                }
            }
            return ctrl as T;
        }

        private static IEnumerable<string> GetPropertiesForObject(this object _this)
        {
            return (from x in _this.GetType().GetProperties() select x.Name).ToList();
        }
        private static object GetPropertyValue(this object _this, string propName)
        {
            var prop = (from x in _this.GetType().GetProperties() where x.Name == propName select x).FirstOrDefault();
            return prop.GetValue(_this);
        }
    }
}
```

Next, let’s see how to use this in a test. You can just start out with a basic class template using the File –> New in Visual Studio. You will see in my example below that I have added some “using” statements to bring in the testing framework while also adding some attributes for CodedUITest and TestMethod. Once you have these in place you can get started writing your test. Since we are not using the Coded UI Test Generator here, we will go ahead and add the items we need on our own. Not only are we going to remove the brittleness here but we are also going to be efficient.

The first thing I do in my test is to open a Browser and go to a url. In my case I am going to our blog. This will open up the browser and navigate all in one line (nifty). Next we are going to start to find the items we need to interact with on the screen. As you can see the first item I am going to go get n my test is the header section. This is a custom html control with the tagname “HEADER.” Once I find this control, I am going to use it in the next section so that I have a container to search within. To be honest, I really don’t have to do this, but I did want to show you that you can search for items using a container instead of having to search the entire DOM every time. Next I will get the search button control and use the “Mouse.Click” operation to click and open the search text box. Once the Coded UI Test finds the search box, it automates the text I want and use and then uses keyboard controls to send the ENTER key for the search.

---

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Input;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.WinControls;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.HtmlControls;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using Keyboard = Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.Keyboard;
using Mouse = Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.Mouse;
using MouseButtons = System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons;

namespace Blog.Example
{
    [CodedUITest]
    public class SimpleUITestWithoutCodedUI
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void SimpleWebTest()
        {
            //open the default browser and navigate to a web page - blog.falafel.com
            BrowserWindow browser = BrowserWindow.Launch(new Uri("http://blog.falafel.com"));
            //we can use controls as a way to narrow down the search for other controls
            var headerSection = browser.SearchFor<HtmlCustom>(new { TagName = "HEADER" });
            //let's search for something
            var searchIcon = headerSection.SearchFor<HtmlHyperlink>(new { href = "http://blog.falafel.com/#searchbox" });
            Mouse.Click(searchIcon);
            var searchInput = browser.SearchFor<HtmlEdit>(new { name = "s" }, new { type = "INPUT" });
            searchInput.Text = "treats and tricks";
            Keyboard.SendKeys("{ENTER}");
            //find our searched for item
            var postToLookFor = browser.SearchFor<HtmlCustom>(new { TagName = "ARTICLE" }, new { InnerText = "31 Days of Visual Studio 2015 Tricks and Treats Blog Post" });
            //validate our search
            Assert.IsTrue(postToLookFor.Exists);
        }
    }
}
```

The next thing I do on the search result screen is find the item that I am interested in evaluating. I made that sound really easy, but having dynamic controls show up and find them is one of the hardest things to do in any Testing Framework. With the power of C# and the flexibility of the Coded UI Framework, I am able to dynamically find my items using search and filter properties so that I can evaluate them. The rest of the test, including the assertion, are basic unit testing techniques.

Answer (score 0):

Like that?

```
    public bool IsVisible(Control control)
    {
        return control.Visible;
    }
```

Comment: Yes like this ...Again if i want to verify whether some label, textbox, grid, table etc any control from Ui is properly visible or not ....and what are the innertext values of those ...so i want such common method which will verify whether given control is exists/visible or not what is values/property of that control ....

Comment: @prakashpandramise could you please share more info? Do you need test method (in test's project) or just method for test (in your actual project)?

Comment: Yes i need test method

Answer (score 0):

I implemented a generic search function as such:

```
public static ControlType IdentifyControlByIdentifierEqualsValue<ControlType>(UITestControl parent, ControlIdentifier identifierTypeAndValue) where ControlType : UITestControl
    {
        var control = (ControlType)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(ControlType), new UITestControl[] { parent });
        control.SearchProperties.Add(identifierTypeAndValue.Type, identifierTypeAndValue.Value);
        var wasFound = control.TryFind();
        if (!wasFound)
            throw new UITestControlNotFoundException("The control of type " + control.GetType().ToString() + " with the identifier type of " + identifierTypeAndValue.Type + " and the identifying attribute of " + identifierTypeAndValue.Value + " was not able to be found");
        return control;
    }
```

With the supporting class

```
public class ControlIdentifier
    {
        public ControlIdentifier(string type, string id)
        {
            Type = type;
            Value = id;
        }
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }
```

Called as such:

```
IdentifyControlByIdentifierEqualsValue<WpfTabList>(workWindow, 
    new ControlIdentifer(WpfButton.PropertyNames.Name, "OK");
```